# Duplicates in not getting ignored

Tags: python

I have below code :

```
def pStockName():

        global StockList

    selfP = []
        StockList = str(raw_input('Enter pipe separated list of StockS : ')).upper().strip()
    items = StockList.split("|")
    count = len(items)
    print  'Total Distinct Stock Count : ',  count
    items = list(set(StockList.split("|")))
    pipelst = [i.replace('-mc','').replace('-MC','').replace('$','').replace('^','') for i in items] 
    filepath = '/location/Stock_Data.txt'
    f = open(filepath, 'r')
    for lns in f:
        split_pipe = lns.split(':', 1)
        if split_pipe[0] in pipelst:
            pipelst.remove(split_pipe[0])
    for lns in pipelst:
        print bcolors.red + lns,' is wrong Stock Name' + bcolors.ENDC
    f.close()
```

when I execute above code it asks me to give some input as below :

> Enter pipe separated list of StockS : aaa|aaa|hma
>
> Total Distinct Stock Count :  3
>
> Stocks Belonging to other  Centers :
>
> Stock Count From Other Center =  0
>
> Stocks Belonging to Current  Centers :
>
> Active Stocks in  US1 :
>
> ^AAA$|^AAA$|^HMA$
>
> Ignored Stock Count From Current Center =  0
>
> You Have Entered StockList belonging to this Center as:
>   ^AAA$|^AAA$|^HMA$
>
> Active Stock Count :  3
>
> Do you wish to continue with these StockS [YES|Y|NO|N] : Y

You are seeing above when I give input (aaa|aaa|hma) and press enter its taking the duplicate entry "aaa" . I want to ignore this duplicate entry when I give the input and press enter. I would like to let you know this input can be as (aaa|AAA) or (AAA|AAA) or (aaa|aaa). Any how any duplicate entry I want to ignore irrespective of upper or lower case.

Please let me know what wrong I did here any how can I fix this.

Comment: You never wrote any code to remove duplicates.  One you create the list 'items' follow the advice in this answer (using sets) to remove duplicates. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/python-removing-duplicates-in-lists

Comment: please learn how to debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [set](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html): ...

```
selfP = []
    StockList = str(raw_input('Enter pipe separated list of StockS : ')).upper().strip()
fullList = StockList.split("|")
items = list(set(fullList))
count = len(items)
```

Comment: the `set` is already in the code. apparently the code does not correspond to the posted output

Comment: @Garlywhale Thanks It worked for me with fullList variable. But that's strange, I have already set in code. But it was not worked by that way. Any ways thanks a lot Gnarlywhale.